# Python - Writing white space to imported CSV data

Tags: python, csv, whitespace, human-readable

I want to:

1. Import CSV formatted data into a python list/array
2. Right justify a 8 space field for the string
3. Write the output as a text file

For example, I want to turn csv data such as:

```
11111, 22,

333, 4444
```

Into:

```
   11111      22

     333    4444
```

My code currently looks like:

```
import csv

input_file = "csv_file.csv"
my_data = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb"), delimiter=',')

for i,j in my_data:
    x = ('%-15s %s\n' % (i,j))

with open('my_output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(x)
```

Thank you

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just `rjust` each element individually and `''.join` them:

```
''.join(elem.rjust(8) for elem in (i,j))
```

Or to write it all out:

```
def join_line(line_iter):
    """
    Take a iterable containing strings and right justify each 
    at 8 spaces before joining
    """
    return ''.join(elem.rjust(8) for elem in line_iter)

with open('output','w') as f:
    f.writelines((join_line(row)+'\n') for row in csv_file)
```

Comment: Thanks mgilson.  Your code works perfectly.  If I want to give 8 spaces to column 1 and 16 spaces to column 2…how would I alter the join_line def?  Thanks again

Comment: Then I think it's better to be explicit:  `f.writelines(col1.rjust(8)+col2.rjust(16)+'\n' for col1,col2 in csv_file`

Comment: Thanks a lot mgilson.  Another great suggestion